# Calculate Weighted Arithmetic Mean with a loop?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, do-loops

In R I can use `weighted.mean`to calculate the Weighted Arithmetic Mean. For example:

```
wt <- c(5,  5,  4,  1)/15
x <- c(3.7,3.3,3.5,2.8)
xm <- weighted.mean(x, wt)
xm
[1] 3.453333
```

I can calculate this "by hand": `wt[1]*x[1]+wt[2]*x[2]+wt[3]*x[3]+wt[4]*x[4]`

I would like to write a loop to do the same. I wrote this code:

```
xm <-0
for(j in length(wt)){
    xm <- xm + wt[j]*x[j]
}
xm
[1] 0.1866667
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just forgot the 1:length(wt)

```
xm <-0
for(j in 1:length(wt)){
xm <- xm + wt[j]*x[j]
}
xm
[1] 3.453333
```

Answer (score 5):

No need for a loop:

```
sum(wt*x)
# [1] 3.453333
```

In R is it more efficient and typically less typing (one line instead of 5 in this case) for you to use vectorized functions like `sum` instead of looping with simple arithmetic operations.